# File uploaded to Amazon S3 from google apps script is corrupted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to upload current active document from google apps script to Amazon S3 by using the below code https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script
and instructions https://engetc.com/projects/amazon-s3-api-binding-for-google-apps-script/

Upload file to  Amazon S3 is successful but getting **"Failed to load PDF document."** while opening file from S3. Looks like file got corrupted during upload to

```
S3 var blob = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs('application/pdf');   
var s3 = new S3('XXXXX', 'XXXX');   
s3.putObject("bucket", blob.getName(), blob, {logRequests:true});
```

Comment: s3 is undefined

Comment: Why are you using a 3rd party API over an AWS SDK - like AWS SDK for JavaScript?

Comment: I am trying to run this in google apps script and I want only S3 service so I chose this third party library.

Comment: S3 is defined and upload is working but while trying to access uploaded file its giving "Failed to load PDF document."

Answer (score 1):

I following the steps in this issue I am able to solve the problem.
https://github.com/eschultink/S3-for-Google-Apps-Script/issues/8

Changes to be made are

S3.gs line 142: change request.setContent(object.getDataAsString()); to request.setContent(object);

S3Request.gs line 60: remove the line if (typeof content != 'string') throw 'content must be passed as a string'

S3Request.gs line 393: replace the function with the following:

```
S3Request.prototype.hexEncodedHash = function(string) {
  if(typeof string === "string")
    return this.hex(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, string, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8));
  else
    return this.hex(Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, string.getBytes()));
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a separate error when using this: 'AWS Error - InvalidRequest: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.' I did some research and it seems it may have to do with the region of my bucket, 'ca-central-1' is there a way to specify the region?

Comment: Same.  Trying to figure out if there is a working implementation anywhere.